# Print media acts differently in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am using `@media` print to generate a report. When I print it in chrome, it is fine, while in Firefox, the components are messed up in the positions. My code is provided as below in two different sections: the first one is the CSS styling and the next one the HTML code.

How can I write this code to work in Chrome and Firefox?

```css
@media print {
    .print-only {
        display: block;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: none !important;
    }

    object {
        width: 160mm;
        height: 120mm;
    }

    button, alert-danger, .no-print {
        display: none !important;
    }

    .top-left-corner-print {
        position: absolute;
        top: 160px;
        left: 50px;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .top-left-print {
        position: absolute;
        top: 160px;
        left: 250px;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .top-print {
        position: absolute;
        top: 156px;
        left: 450px;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .top-right-print {
        position: absolute;
        top: 160px;
        left: 650px;
        font-size: 14px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    .top-left-print-second-row {
        position: absolute;
        top: 565px;
        left: 60px;
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .top-left-print-third-row {
        position: absolute;
        top: 950px;
        left: 60px;
        width: 200px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .print-audiogram-graph {
        border: none !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: -170px;
        left: 10px;
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
    }

    .print-abTest-graph {
        border: none !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 540px;
        left: 50px;
        width: 40%;
        height: 40%;
    }

    .tympanometry-print {
        border: none !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 610px;
        left: 420px;
    }

    .ipsi-reflex-print {
        border: none !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 780px;
        left: 420px;
    }

    .contra-reflex-print {
        border: none !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 920px;
        left: 420px;
    }

    .comment-print {
        position: absolute;
        top: 1010px;
        left: 40px;
        width: 360px;
        word-break: break-all;
    }

    .no-border-print {
        border: none;
    }

    aside#sidebar, header[role="banner"], footer, #comments, #respond {
        display: none;
    }

    .page-header {
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="h2 page-header">Audiology Session</div>
<div class="alert alert-info top-buffer no-border-print" data-bind="with: metadata">
    <div class="row">
        <h4 class="col-md-6 top-left-corner-print" id="">
            Client: <a data-bind="text: subjectName"></a>
        </h4>
        <h4 class="col-md-4 top-left-print">
            Date: <span data-bind="text: date"></span>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="top-buffer"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <h4 class="col-md-6 top-right-print">
            Clinician: <a data-bind="text: clinicianName"></a>
        </h4>
        <h4 class="col-md-4 no-print">
            Clinic:
            <span data-bind="css: { performedByBsh: performedByBsh }">
                <span data-bind="text: clinic, css: { bshClinicUnset: bshClinicUnset }"></span>
            </span>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="text-align:left; width:750px; max-width:100%">
    <h3 class="no-print" style="margin-top:50px">Audiograms</h3>
    <p class="top-print">Transducer: <span data-bind="text: transducer"></span></p>
    <object class="print-audiogram-graph" id="audiogram-graph" type="image/svg+xml" data="~/Content/audiogram.svg" style="border:1px solid gray">
        Your browser does not support svg objects.
    </object>
</div>
<div style="text-align:left; width:450px; max-width:100%">
    <h3 class="top-left-print-second-row" style="margin-top:50px">A/B Tests</h3>
    <object class="print-abTest-graph" id="ab-test-graph" type="image/svg+xml" data="~/Content/abTest.svg" style="border:1px solid gray">
        Your browser does not support svg objects.
    </object>
</div>

<div>
    <h3 class="no-print" style="margin-top:50px">Tympanometry</h3>
    <div data-bind="with: $data.tympanometry()">
        <div class="AudiologySession no-print" data-bind="visible: canShowTympanometryFields">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/_TympanometryPartial.cshtml")
        </div>
        <div class="print-only">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/_TympanometryPrintOnly.cshtml")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <h3 class="no-print" style="margin-top:50px">Reflexes</h3>
    <div data-bind="with:reflexes">
        <div class="AudiologySession no-print" data-bind="visible: canShowReflexFields">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/_ReflexPartial.cshtml")
        </div>
        <div class="print-only">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Person/_ReflexPrintOnly.cshtml")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<h3 class="top-left-print-third-row" style="margin-top:50px">Comments</h3>
<div class="comment-print" data-bind="with:metadata">
    <div data-bind="visible: !editor.editing()">
        <span data-bind="text: comment"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: editor.editing()">
        <textarea maxlength="200" placeholder="Your comment&#x2026;" type="text" data-bind="value: comment"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: What specifically is different between the two?  Can you narrow this down to a small reproducible example?

Comment: I was initially trying to put different objects in a report format (when user press ctrl + p) where some objects were optional. Saying that it was so difficult to rearrange the items on the report. The solution I came up with was using a grid to specify the main areas and then using a flex in a specific area where then objects are optional; therefore the browser can rearrange them automatically based on their existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find the best solution but using mm instead of px helped a lot to get a more close behavior in Firefox and Chrome and also using flex as follows in my css:

```
@media print {
    .print-only {
        display: block;
    }

    .wrapper-print {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 40% 10% 30% 20%;
        grid-template-rows: 6mm 6mm 103mm auto auto;
    }
    .print-content-box {
        grid-row: 4;
        grid-column: 1/5;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column wrap;
        max-height: 140mm;
    }
.
.
.
```

and in the html:

```
<div class="print-content-box">
    <div class="1">
    .
    .
    .
    </div>
    <div class="2">
    .
    .
    .
    </div>
.
.
.
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, you'll definitely have better luck using units for the device.  What I normally do is size everything on `em`.  `1 em` is readable on everything by default, and it's easy to set a base size in a different dimension like millimeters or inches if needed.